# HTML. how to make a blank page

Tags: javascript, html, css

lets say i have a normal website page. it irrelevant what is on it. how can i use javascript and html to make the page complete blank (white). i tried this already:

```
<body style='z-index:9999;position:absolute;background:#ffffff url('http://removed/bg.jpg') repeat right top;width:1000%;height:1000%;'></body>
```

but it doesn't cover anything. how can i do this? i just want the whole page to go blank when i click a button.

i am not sure why it is saying this dos not meet standards. but i think i need to write more.

Comment: what do you mean 'blank'? you can document.location.href='about:blank' or you can cover the page with a div or you $.fn.hide the page...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script>
var eventListener = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var clickEvent = eventListener == "attachEvent" ? "onclick" : "click";

document.getElementById('buttonId')[eventListener](clickEvent, function(){
  document.body.style.display = "none";
});
<script>

<button id="buttonId">click me</button
```

Comment: thank you, that is great, just what i was looking for, i cant accept the answer for another few minutes

Comment: As a general rule, using onClick events in the body of your HTML is a practice best avoided.

Comment: @gaoshan88 but then that wasn't the question. he only asked how to hide the body. and i used for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Right. Your answer fulfills that. I am simply pointing out that it isn't the best way to go about doing it. May as well show best practice when possible, especially for someone who is new to things.

Answer (score 0):

Because the body's background is alway behind the elements. Put the style into a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the head of the page

```
<style>
body {
   background: #fff; 
   color: #fff;
}

body > * {
   display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a page go blank when clicking a button (using jQuery):

In your HTML:

```
<button id="blankit">Begone!</button>
```

Your JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#blankit').click(function(){
        $('body').hide();
    });
});
```